# Updating Root/Intermediate Certificates over NDES/SCEP

Tags: certificates, cisco, scep

In attempts to setup our first instance of NDES/SCEP in the wild on Cisco routers we have run into a concern.

Currently our organization has a three tier PKI. We have an AD CS server on the third tier running NDES. All aspects of the system are functioning, but through discussion and testing we have a concern.

**How do Root and Intermediary CA certificates get updated on the end device?**

If we have a router configured and functioning with a trusted CA/RA using SCEP, but the issuing CA certificate is nearing expiration will the SCEP service execute the GetCACert command again to refresh the local cache of the issuing certificate?

[SCEP RFC (draft-nourse-scep-23)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nourse-scep-23#section-4.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thomas Pornin provided an acceptable answer for a similar question at:

[Renewing Microsoft Certificate Services Root Certificate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2865/renewing-microsoft-certificate-services-root-certificate)